Remove rows based on count of a specific value?
I have clustered a bunch of lidar points using dbscan to improve classification of vegetation points. The output of dbscan is a new column with a cluster_ID that corresponds to which group the lidar point belongs to.
What I want to do is remove any clusters that are below a certain number of points. My data has over 70 000 points with about 600 classes, so my working solution is a for loop with if statement but it takes about 2 mins to complete. I am hoping to speed this up as this is a small subset of my actual data.
Here is a working example of what I implemented in my code that works but is slow:
rm(list=ls()) # clear env

# make empty list
test_data <- c()

# add data to cluster by
test_data$cluster_ID <- as.integer(runif(10,min = 1, max = 5))

# convert to df
test_data <- as.data.frame(test_data)

# summarize by cluster
sum_test <- test_data %>% group_by(cluster_ID) %>%
  summarise(pt_count = sum(cluster_ID))

# convert from sum to num points
sum_test$pt_count <- sum_test$pt_count/sum_test$cluster_ID

# remove all rows < 3 points in "cluster_ID"
for (c_id in unique(test_data$cluster_ID)) {
  # get index of unique c_id
  idx <- which(test_data$cluster_ID == c_id)
  
  # filter out length < 3 and remove from test_data
  if (length(idx) < 3) {
    test_data <- test_data[-c(idx)]
  }
}

What I can't figure out is how find the rows in test_data that are less then a count threshold based on the output of the summarise function without a loop since the lengths of test_data and sum_test are not equal.
Thanks for any help/suggestions.

Please provide example input data dput(mydata), and expected output.

Why are we summing the cluster_IDs?

The data example I made is almost exactly what I get from DBscan but with only a few rows. I am also not able to publicly share my data :(
Summing of the cluster_ID is what I was thinking to use as an easy way to remove cluster of points less than a certain threshold.

# make empty list
test_data <- c()

# add data to cluster by
test_data$cluster_ID <- as.integer(runif(10,min = 1, max = 5))

# convert to df
test_data <- as.data.frame(test_data)

# summarize by cluster
sum_test <- test_data %>% add_count(cluster_ID)

sum_test %>% filter(n < 3)

I may be misunderstanding the problem. But I think perhaps you just want to add_count rather than summarise there? add_count(x) is basically just group_by(x) %>% mutate(n = n()), and I think that's the root of the problem - you don't want summarise you want mutate so that you don't reduce the number of rows. And then you can just filter.
